# Redirect missing images in a specific directory

Tags: nginx

I have a directory of images at `/img/`.  When a request is made to an image in that directory that does not exist, I would like to serve `/img/default.jpg`.  How would I add this to my nginx configuration?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Do this:

```
location /img {
  try_files $uri /img/default.jpg;
}
```

That will not redirect the request to default.jpg, but instead the file contents of their request will be served with the default.jpg contents instead.

More info here:
http://nginx.org/en/docs/http/ngx_http_core_module.html#try_files

Redirecting would be pretty messy and would need to make use of the if directive. You can do that too though. More info here: http://nginx.org/en/docs/http/ngx_http_rewrite_module.html#if